# Phenomenon that have $\sqrt{x}$ functions? Grading curve, inverse-square law, etc?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

[image]

I am primarily interested in the NATURE of square root functions. ie: What kinds of behavior, situations, or models are best described with a square root function ?

I have seen a grading curve scale as $y=10\sqrt{x}$
This makes lower grades increase much more than higher grades.
This is illustrated on the graph above where it is steeper for lower x values.

```
x   10*sqrt(x)
--------------
0    0
1    10
25   50
49   70
64   80
81   90
100  100
```

What are some other situations where the main theme is that lower numbers are magnified and higher numbers, not so much?

Does the inverse-square law of gravity apply here?  The lower the distance, the higher the gravitational pull (and not in a linear manner, but a squared relationship) <-- what is the right phrasing of that idea?

Comment: Note that the “inverse-square” law refers to an $r^{-2}$ term in the formula, not to an $r^{1/2}$ term.

Comment: There are square root laws that apply to perception of stimuli, e.g., light and sound. Try googling "stimulus square root".

Comment: What about the [Torricelli's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torricelli%27s_law)? Is it things like this you ask for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time it takes an object beginning at rest to fall a distance $h$ (constant gravity over the distance, air or other resistence neglected) is proportional to $\sqrt {h}.$

This reminds me of something I once wondered about (early to mid 1990s, and I used my reasoning on a teaching statement in 1996), and which I posted a description of in this [18 January 2001 k12.ed.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=1142751) archived at Math Forum. An excerpt of that post follows:

> Related to this is something I wondered about a few years ago, and the analysis of it surprised me. If you watch little bugs crawl about, it seems that their reaction times are much better than ours. Also, if something falls from a height of $1$ mm or $2$ mm, it takes too little time for us to see it falling. So I wondered how things falling from $1$ mm or so are perceived by tiny bugs. Do they perceive objects to fall at a faster rate, the same rate, or a slower rate than we perceive objects to fall, when the objects fall a distance roughly equal to their size? That is, a $1$ mm bug watches something fall from a $1$ mm height, while a (tall) $2$ m person watches something fall from a $2$ m height. I believe the answer is slower.
>
> Let $h$ denote the length of the organism. The time it takes an object to fall from a height $h$ is proportional to $\sqrt h$ (high school physics), while an organism's reaction time is proportional to $h$ (nerve impulses travel roughly at a constant rate). As $h$ becomes smaller and smaller, the values of $\sqrt h$ become larger and larger relative to the values of $h.$ Thus, if we were as small as ants and dropped something, it would appear to slowly float down to the ground.

Comment: That falling object example.  In the beginning, it moves slowly.  Later on, it moves faster and faster.  If I were to graph speed, wouldn't it look more like an exponential than a square root curve (which is flattening out like a log curve)

Comment: @JackOfAll: Its *speed* is linear with time (i.e. $v = Ct$ for some constant $C),$ while the *total distance traveled* is quadratic with time (i.e. $d = Kt^2$ for some constant $K).$ Indeed, $C$ = $g$ and $K = \frac{1}{2}g,$ where $g$ is the acceleration of gravity.

Comment: Right, so distance traveled is parabolic.  But, isn't speed increasing with time?  It's not constant.  It's getting faster as it falls (until it hits terminal velocity)

Comment: @JackOfAll: The function $v(t) = Ct$ is an increasing function, at least for a nonzero and positive constant $C.$ The graph of this function is a line with slope $C.$

Comment: What kinds of behavior, situations, or models are best described with a square root function ?

Comment: @JackOfAll: Googling both these phrases together will give you a lot of examples: "square root" "word problems" As for which are *best* described in this way, that's a much more difficult question whose answer will vary with the person doing the judging.

Comment: Yea, word problems will not give authentic real world examples, but just some stuff from a textbook, written by someone who doesn't use math to make a living.    I have one of those, and that's not what I'm looking for.  I want to know of functions that level off in your personal life.

Comment: @JackOfAll: Maybe these will be of help: [root mean square speed in chemistry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_speed) and [root mean square noise in electronics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_(electronics)), [length contraction in special relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction), [effects of length, area, and volume scaling in biology](http://fathom.lib.uchicago.edu/2/21701757/), and [The distance to which the radar can detect an object is proportional to the square root of the object's size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_astronomy).

Answer (score 1):

The charachteristic of $\sqrt x$ that interests you appear to be that its derivative (ie how much is it steep) if $\displaystyle \frac1{2\sqrt x}$. This means that for $x$ very small, $\displaystyle \frac1{2\sqrt x}$ is very big (so the curve is very steep); for $x$ very large, $\displaystyle \frac1{2\sqrt x}$ is very small.

You can find any number of function that behave this way. For example $\log(x)$, $\sqrt[n]x$ etc.

In general think of any function $f(x)$ such that $f(x) \to \infty$ if $x$ is small, and $f(x) \to 0$ if $x$ is large; then $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt$ will behave in a similar fashion

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, these fn's would exhibit the derivative behavior you described.   But, I am primarily interested in the NATURE of square root functions.  ie:  What kinds of behavior, situations, or models are best described with a square root function ?

Comment: What kinds of behavior, situations, or models are best described with a square root function ?

Comment: @JackOfAll Well every time you see something like $x = t^2$, you can turn the question around and ask "what if I want $t$ in terms of $x$?" In this case you've got a square root. So example of models described with squares are also example of models described with square roots. I don't know any specific example though!